# Document to .jpg converter

Tags: c#, .net, converters

We're looking for an all around document converter to create small thumbnails for previewing in our asp.net project. So far we've encountered a handfull of difficult to use/document commandline tools that can convert one filetype to jpg, but we're looking for an all around solution. ( xls, doc, pdf to jpg ). Does anybody know any solutions for this problem with a pricetag that doesn't exceed 700- 1500 $?

Comment: Convert online! http://pdf2jpg.net/

Comment: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

Comment: http://www.zamzar.com/convert/doc-to-jpg/

Comment: http://www.pptx2ppt.com/convert/xls-to-jpg.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Rachel, but we need something that can be used programmaticlly so it happens in the code behind. We have allot of documents going to the server, and everytime one gets send, before it's proccessed we need to create a small thumbnail image, so the document can be previewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just an Idea About Creating Thumbnails.

You will have to use `image.GetThumbnailImage()` method.

It works as follows:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(fName);
Image thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(120, 120, ()=>false, IntPtr.Zero);
thumb.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fName, "thumb"));
```

**MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it out and let you know how it went.